# How to find all readonly fileds using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html.textboxfor

I have several text boxes with attribute 'readonly'

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientNumber, new {@readonly = "readonly", @class ="message-label"})
```

How can I find all of them using jQuery (to enable similar behavior on keydown event)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well use attribute seletor..

```
 $('input[readonly="readonly"]').keydown(function(){
     .....
 });
```

or just

```
$('input[readonly]').keydown(function(){..});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 $('input[type="textbox"][readonly]').on('keydown', someHandler);
```

or shorter:

```
 $(':text[readonly]').on('keydown', someHandler); //less performance effective than the previous one.
```

Also if you have a container that holds these and you know the container seelctor then this would be much faster.

```
 $('containerSelector').find('input[type="textbox"][readonly]').on('keydown', someHandler);
```